# commands in latex hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

In the last weeks I tried to work with LaTeX hyphenation functionality.

`\c{e8\9es}`

In the description at the end of this document `\c` is discribed as lower case letter but this doesn't make sense. So could it be that this command is the special sign *cedilla* and how can it be that two digits are written side by side without letter between them?

Comment: Did you get notified when I extended (and commented) my answer to your first question? (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60237/hyphenation-in-latex)

Answer (score 3):

In the file `dehyphn.tex`, `\c{}` is a no-op, so writing `\c{e8\9es}` is equivalent to writing `e8\9es`. Why is that? Because the same file, just with a different definition of `\c` can be used for the "old font" hyphenation patterns (`dehypht.tex`).

The string `e8\9es` is then translated into

```
e8^^Yes
```

which represents in internal format the pattern

eßes

and the 8 between `e` and `ß` means that no hyphenation is to be tried in that place: only another pattern where there's a 9 (say, just by way of example, `xe9\9esa`) could countermand such a statement.